# SQL Count based on like statement and Group by

Tags: sql, count, pivot, aggregate-functions, sql-like

I have a table similar to below structure. I need to get count of Failed, Success and Partial Success based on value of MessageValue column. If Messagevale column contains 'failed' then it is Failed, 'success' is considered Success and 'partial success' as Partial failure. So i need to check LIKE criteria within the count and also i need it based on date. I tried with Count with Group by , but didn't get what I needed.

```
Date                   MessageValue
-----------------------------------------------
10/18/2020             Process failed some text here
10/18/2020             Process success some text here
10/19/2020             Partial success some text here
10/19/2020             Process failed some text here
10/19/2020             Process failed some text here
10/19/2020             Process partial success some text here
10/20/2020             Process partial success some text here
------------------------------------------------
```

So output should be like below.

```
Date                   Success      Failure     Partial Failure
-----------------------------------------------------------------
10/18/2020               1             1            0
10/19/2020               1             2            1
10/20/2020               0             0            1
```

Comment: `sum(case when col like '%failure%' then 1 else 0 end)` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation on `like` condition. This seems to do what you want:

```
select
    date,
    sum(case when col like '%success%' and col not like '%partial success%' then 1 else 0 end) success,
    sum(case when col like '%failed%' then 1 else 0 end) failure,
    sum(case when col like '%partial failed%' then 1 else 0 end) partial_success
from mytable
group by date
```